# When I save changes for css and js in my WP localhost env windows 10 the changes don't take effects immediately!

Tags: theme-development, cache, localhost

**Hey guys** I am developing a wp theme, and I am using for localhost server XAMPP and Wampserver.So anytime I save my changes specially for css and js it doesn't take effects immediately! sometimes it can takes up to 24h for the changes to take effects, how can I solve this issue, it really slowdown my work???

Comment: Where do you view your work? In the web? When you save the code and open your project in web you can clear the cache. This should work and the changes should come up immediately. Try this and when it works you can download "Clear Cache" for Google Chrome and do this with just one click.

Comment: The above comment was posted as an answer not a comment, and the reply was lost during the conversion process, the OP replied with "Hi, thanks for comment. Yes I use chrome and I do clear cache"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the version number on .css and .js files when you change them. That can be a real pain while you are developing so you can use a random number.

```
    $randomizr = $rand = rand( 1, 99999999999 );// Enqueue scripts and styles

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/my-script.js', array('jquery'), $randomizr, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers. I fixed this issue with [wp_super_cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugin and I also converted my css file to sass. And I clear my browser and time I save my changes (css and js )